# Draw vector of closest approach between two vtkPolyData objects?

Tags: python, geometry, distance, vtk

I am using vtk trying to determine the minimum distance between two polydata objects. I am using `vtkDistancePolyDataFilter` to determine the minimum distance, but how do I determine the associated x,y,z points on each object that define this minimum result?

The minimal example below colors the cube based on distance to the cylinder; I would like instead to draw a `vtkLine` between the closest points on each `vtkPolyData` object. The  result of the `vtkDistancePolyDataFilter` appears to include the cells, normals and distances for the cube object, but I don't know how to easily pull out which of these is associated with the minimum distance or how this relates to points on the cylinder.

**Edit:** I'm not confident that `vtkDistancePolyDataFilter` is correctly calculating the minimum distance - it appears to only do vertex-vertex interactions.

```
import vtk

ren = vtk.vtkRenderer()
renWin = vtk.vtkRenderWindow()
renWin.AddRenderer(ren)
iren = vtk.vtkRenderWindowInteractor()
iren.SetRenderWindow(renWin)

cube = vtk.vtkCubeSource()
cube.SetCenter (1.2, 0.3, 0.4);

transform = vtk.vtkTransform()
transform.RotateX(45)
transform.RotateY(45)
transform.Translate((1.2,0.2,0))

tf = vtk.vtkTransformPolyDataFilter()
tf.SetInput(cube.GetOutput())
tf.SetTransform(transform)
tf.Update()

cubeMapper = vtk.vtkPolyDataMapper()
cubeMapper.SetInput(tf.GetOutput())
cubeActor = vtk.vtkActor()
cubeActor.SetMapper(cubeMapper)

#Create Cylinder
cylinder = vtk.vtkCylinderSource()
cylinder.SetHeight(2)
cylinderMapper = vtk.vtkPolyDataMapper()
cylinderMapper.SetInput(cylinder.GetOutput())
cylinderActor = vtk.vtkActor()
cylinderActor.SetMapper(cylinderMapper)

#Determine distance btwn Cylinder and Cube
distfilt = vtk.vtkDistancePolyDataFilter()
distfilt.SetInputConnection(1, tf.GetOutputPort())
distfilt.SetInputConnection(0, cylinder.GetOutputPort())
distfilt.Update()

#Color the cube based on distance to cylinder
distmapper = vtk.vtkPolyDataMapper()
distmapper.SetInputConnection(distfilt.GetOutputPort(1))
distmapper.SetScalarRange( \
    distfilt.GetOutput().GetPointData().GetScalars().GetRange()[0],
    distfilt.GetOutput().GetPointData().GetScalars().GetRange()[1],)

distactor = vtk.vtkActor()
distactor.SetMapper(distmapper)

distarray = distfilt.GetOutput().GetPointData().GetScalars()
for i in range(24):
    print distarray.GetValue(i)
    # Minimum distance is the lowest of these results, but what are the
    # Corresponding points on the cylinder and cube?

scalarBar = vtk.vtkScalarBarActor()
scalarBar.SetLookupTable(distmapper.GetLookupTable())
scalarBar.SetTitle("Distance")
scalarBar.SetNumberOfLabels(5)

ren.AddActor(cubeActor)
ren.AddActor(cylinderActor)
ren.AddActor(distactor)
ren.AddActor2D(scalarBar)

iren.Initialize()
renWin.Render()
iren.Start()
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This cannot be done directly with VTK - a physics / kinematics / collision library is required. I'm currently looking at what would be involved in getting Bullet working with VTK.