# Distance between to non-convex 3D objects

Tags: c++, 3d, geometry, vtk

I'm currently using VTK to load several non-convex 3D objects (polyhedron as `vtkPolyData`) and I want to compute the minimum distances between pairs of these objects. For this I am using `vtkSmartPointer<vtkDistancePolyDataFilter>` with the two `vtkPolyData` as input.

My first question is: Am I assuming right, that this method computes the distance between each vertex-vertex-pair of both input objects (see http://www.vtk.org/Wiki/VTK/Examples/Cxx/PolyData/DistancePolyDataFilter)? I have read at several pages that one cannot compute the minimum distance between two 3D objects this way; is this right? If so, why wouldn't it work this way?

If it is possible to compute the minimum distance of the two objects with this example, then I have two further questions:

How can I determine the point at an input 3D object, where the distance is minimum to the second input object? In other words, how do I get the value from the distancePolyDataFilter-output with the minimum distance?

**EDIT**: I used another example to measure the distance between each vertex-vertex pair of the two `vtkPolyData`, so that I can now access the point of the first `vtkPolyData`, at which the distance to the second `vtkPolyData` is minimum:

`double vtkImplicitPolyDataDistance::EvaluateFunction(double x[3])`

But I don't know how to get the point of the second `vtkPolyData` (the corresponding point for the minimum distance).

Secondly, is there any common way to reduce the set of points in the two `vtkPolyData`, so that I don't have to compute/compare each vertex-vertex-pair? For each pair of 3D objects, for which I want to compute the minimum distance, I can roughly determine their relative position to wach other. For example I know that object two lies above object one in x-direction. But since the objects are non-convex I cannot say that the maximum x-value of object one is smaller than the minimum x-value of object two. I also know that my 3D objects do not intersect, so there is always a positive minimum distance between them (but again, as the objects are non-convex I cannot work with bounding boxes (or at least I cannot think of any way how to use them)).

Comment: In this question (https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15939098/draw-vector-of-closest-approach-between-two-vtkpolydata-objects) there is something said related to my questions but the answer is not really helpful for me. Since I cannot comment there, I'm just linking to this question.

Comment: Dunno about VTK, but the most efficient way is probably splitting each object in convex polyhedra and the run VClip (voronoi clipping) on each pair. Some kind of indexing (like RTree or quadtree) could be useful depending on the typical configuration.

Comment: For the questions at the end of your second paragraph, imagine a tetrahedron pointing directly at the centre of the face of a cube. The shortest distance is between the closest vertex of the tetrahedron and the centre of the face; all the cube's vertices are further away.

Comment: @AlanStokes: Thanks, I didn't think about that. For now vertex-to-vertex distance will do it.

Answer (score 0):

> I have read at several pages that one cannot compute the minimum distance between two 3D objects this way [between each vertex-vertex-pair of both input objects]; is this right? If so, why wouldn't it work this way?

I was wondering this same question and here is an example illustrating how two meshes can be closer than any of their vertex pairs are.
[image]

The red points are their closest points which are not vertices.

Sorry, I cannot speak to the VTK example.